# facing problem while executing vb.net query

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
        con = New SqlConnection("server=chinna; uid=sa; pwd=136018@h; database=icms")
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select pass from personal where idno=" & TextBox1.Text, con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim rdr As SqlDataReader
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If rdr.Read() Then

            TextBox2.Text = rdr.ToString()
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
        Else
            MsgBox("incorrect password")
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulerability.

Comment: What problems are you facing?
You give very little information altho you can already spot some error, but more information wouldn't be a bad thing.

Comment: You should name your textboxes.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text!**

Comment: I would also remove your username and password, I have done it, but it is forever in the history of this edits :(

Comment: @Dustin: I just flagged this for moderator attention.  Hopefully they can remove that info quickly.

Comment: I don't have the capability to purge revisions.  I emailed team@stackoverflow.com, but since your user/pass has already been compromised, I suggest changing it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use parameters in your query:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("select pass from personal where idno=@param", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param", TextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead of `ExecuteReader`.

```
Dim password As String
password = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString()
```

FYI, storing passwords in plain text and comparing like this is VERY bad practice. You should be encrypting the passwords with some one-way salted encryption and then doing the same on verification then comparing the encrypted values.

Comment: Yes, but then you should be iterating through the reading, not just dumping it to a string.

Comment: +1 for sticking to the answer and only commenting on the (OMG VERY) bad coding practices later.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the DataSource assignment.

Add `GridView1.DataSource = rdr` before you call DataBind.

Your If block should look like:

```
If rdr.Read() Then  
 GridView1.Visible = True             
 GridView1.DataSource = rdr
 GridView1.DataBind()           
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("select pass from personal where idno='" & TextBox1.Text & "'", con)
```

beyond that code seems for ASP.net. We can not execute MsgBox in VB.net that can appear on client browser.

Comment: Putting in the quotes will make it work, but leaves a SQL injection attack vulnerability. If the text in the text box contains a ', then you could be in real trouble, i.e. the text "test';DROP TABLE personal;GO'"

Answer (score 0):

use `HasRows` on rdr and set `DataSource`for GridView1

```
    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If rdr.HasRows Then
        GridView1.Visible = True
        GridView1.DataSource = rdr
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your error or are you just getting a null for rdr?

I don't see an outpout paramenter. You need one. You only have an input parameter.

Comment: You don't need an output parameter to get the result of a SELECT query.  The results of the query are the output.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to somehow mark that the user was logged in, using a Session variable or a login identity.  Otherwise, anyone can go to the logged in version of the page by simply navigating directly to  it.
2. `MsgBox(` is not valid in asp.net, because it would display a message on the server, not on the client.  Try using a `Label` on the page to display error messages by setting its text.
3. What is the problem you are having?  Does it just "not work"?  Does it not validate your password correctly?  Do you get an exception of some sort?  Can you post the results?