# facing problem in executing query

Tags: sql, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [facing problem while executing vb.net query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833289/facing-problem-while-executing-vb-net-query)

i am unable to **show the result in gridview** by executing th equery i.e

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
        con = New SqlConnection("server=chinna; uid=sa; pwd=136018@h; database=icms;")
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from personal where idno=@param", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param", TextBox1.Text)


        Dim rdr As SqlDataReader
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If rdr.Read() Then
            GridView1.Visible = True
            GridView1.DataBind()


        End If
```