# facing problem in executing query

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [facing problem while executing vb.net query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833289/facing-problem-while-executing-vb-net-query)

I am trying to get with the password verification from backend, and login to the page but I was not able to do this.  My query is:

```
    Dim con As SqlConnection
    con = New SqlConnection("server=chinna; uid=XXXXXX; pwd=XXXXXXX; database=self")
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    cmd = New SqlCommand("select PASSWORD from employees where EmployeeNumber=@param", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param", TextBox1.Text)
    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If TextBox2.Text = rdr.ToString() then
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
    Else
        MsgBox("incorrect password")
```